# Как вставить видео из OpenCV во внутренний content PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, opencv, qt-designer, qvideowidget

При нажатии на кнопку воспроизвести, запускается видео в отдельном окне.

Как сделать так чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, видео открывалось не в новом окне, а в окне приложения PyQt?

Пытался вот так: 
`ui.QWidget.imshow('frame', frame)` 
но не получается.

---

**main.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
from design import Ui_Form
import cv2


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
ui = Ui_Form()
ui.setupUi(Form)
Form.show()

# Hook logic
def PlayVideo():
    video = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
    while(video.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = video.read()
        if ret == True:
            cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(28) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        else:
            break
    video.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(PlayVideo)

# Main loop

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**design.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(824, 452)
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 30, 561, 341))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet(".QFrame {\n"
"    background-color: #fff;\n"
"}")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 380, 561, 23))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet(".QPushButton {\n"
"    background: #222;\n"
"    color: #fff;\n"
"    text-align: center\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Воспроизвести"))
```

Comment: `opencv` использует свое окно, а `qt` используется свое, поэтому просто так это не сделать. Нужно в отдельном брать кадры из opencv и отправлять их на виджет Qt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не знаю насколько вам важно использовать библиотеку `cv2`,
но для начала предлагаю вам попробовать вариант без ее использования.

Класс `QVideoWidget` предоставляет виджет, который представляет видео, созданное медиа-объектом.

PS. Если для вас важно использование `OpenCV` - напишите, что-нибудь придумаем :)

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QSize
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaContent, QMediaPlayer
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget


class VideoWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(300, 300))
        self.resize(500, 500)
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.button = QPushButton('Play', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.playMedia)
        
        video_widget = QVideoWidget(self)
        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(self, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(video_widget)
        #                                                           vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv <-- установите свое
        self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile("Samonastrojka.avi")))
        
        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(video_widget)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.button)

    def playMedia(self):
        if self.mediaPlayer.state() == QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.mediaPlayer.pause()
            self.button.setText('Play')
        else:
            self.mediaPlayer.play()
            self.button.setText('Pause')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    player = VideoWindow()
    player.show()
    exitCode = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(exitCode)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: QVideoWidget можно кормить сырым видео? h264 без контейнера у меня есть.

Comment: а вот нашел  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#setMedia

Answer (score 0):

Для объединения [opencv](/questions/tagged/opencv) и [q](/questions/tagged/q) можно поступить так:

- В отдельном потоке считываются кадры из заданного источника через `opencv` и сигналом их передавать
- В окне виджета этот поток создается и запускается, а кадры размещаются на виджете (в данном случае на `QLabel`)

*Но я бы рекомендовал использовать встроенные средства Qt, если это возможно. Для этого есть модули `QtMultimedia` и `QtMultimediaWidgets`*

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/fb11a97bd1b8ce3d6e2fa1f65d2acb2246dd1508/opencv__examples/show_with_pyqt5.py#L16)

```
import sys

import cv2
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap

from design import Ui_Form


class ThreadOpenCV(QThread):
    changePixmap = pyqtSignal(QImage)

    def __init__(self, source):
        super().__init__()

        self.source = source

    def run(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.source)
        while True:
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if ret:
                # https://stackoverflow.com/a/55468544/6622587
                rgbImage = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                h, w, ch = rgbImage.shape
                bytesPerLine = ch * w
                convertToQtFormat = QImage(rgbImage.data, w, h, bytesPerLine, QImage.Format_RGB888)
                p = convertToQtFormat.scaled(640, 480, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
                self.changePixmap.emit(p)

                cv2.waitKey(28)


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.label_video = QLabel()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.label_video)

        self.ui.frame.setLayout(layout)

        self.thread = ThreadOpenCV("video.mp4")
        self.thread.changePixmap.connect(self.setImage)

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.playVideo)

    def playVideo(self):
        self.thread.start()

    def setImage(self, image):
        self.label_video.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

mw = Widget()
mw.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, а как установить QtMultimedia в QtDesigner? ОС Windows

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста, описал вопрос более подробно здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1211295/qtdesigner-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-multimedia-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8b

Comment: @ViktorK, а как это относится к моему ответу? :) [Если ответ помог, то проголосуйте и примите его](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)