# QtDesigner как добавить multimedia виджеты?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, видео, qt-designer

Как в `Qt Designer` добавить визуальные виджеты `QtMultimedia`, например как здесь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: зачем тебе дизайнер? Вручную делай

Comment: https://forum.qt.io/topic/70488/pyqt5-and-qt-designer-video-player-question

Comment: @Lofectr Почему?